# JQuery Ajax Get TypeError: Illegal invocation

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring

I am trying to send an ajax get request with jquery but I am getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
>       at e (jquery.min.js:4)
>       at dc (jquery.min.js:4)
>       at dc (jquery.min.js:4)
>       at Function.n.param (jquery.min.js:4)
>       at Function.ajax (jquery.min.js:4)
>       at home.js:2

```
   var cid = document.getElementById("id").value;
$.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    url : windowLocationS + "findTourByCustomId",
    data : {
        id : cid
    },
    async : false,
    cache : false,
    dataType : "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    success : function(jsn) {
        console.log(jsn.length);
    },
    error : function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value= "/findTourByCustomId", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public List<classA> findTourByCustomId(@RequestParam(value = "id", required = true) String id) {
        return service.findByCustomId(id);
    }
```

How can I get the data successfully?

Comment: Is the js code snippet you've place in your question is your `home.js` file?

Comment: @eeya yes, the code snippet is in `home.js`

Comment: If we may, Can update your question and show us how do you include the `<script>` tags that you've called your `jquery.js` and your `home.js`?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/Home/Index900",  //I changed this url
                data: {
                    theId: "fromCid"    //changed id to theId to avoid routing issues, and simplified string from cid
                },
                async: false,
                cache: false,
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (jsn) {  
                    console.log(jsn.length);
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    alert("error");
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
```

Here is my server code, in case you need it.  It may be in a different language:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index900(string theId)
    {
        return Json("AwordThatLettersWillCount", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public ActionResult Index800()
    {
        return View();
    }
```